# Longer Training Times with Larger Batch Sizes on open_lm-research/open_llama_7b_v2 using Qlora

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, llama

I'm facing an issue with the 'openlm-research/open_llama_7b_v2' model using Qlora where increasing the per_device_train_batch_size unexpectedly extends training time.

Configuration:

```
Model: openlm-research/open_llama_7b_v2
Method: Qlora
Batch size: 1 (3GB GPU, 4hrs) vs. 128 (8GB GPU, 40hrs)
gradient_accumulation_steps:

GPU: 4X A100 40GB
Transformers version: 4.30.0.dev0
```

Issue:
Training time increases drastically from 4 hours (per_device_train_batch_size 1) to 40 hours (per_device_train_batch_size 128), despite the GPU handling the larger batch size without memory issues.

Code:

```
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)


model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    config['model_id'],
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=config.get('device_map', 'auto')
)

# Initialize tokenizer

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(config['model_id'])
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

# Define LoRA configuration
qlora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=config['lora_r'],#16,
    lora_alpha=config['lora_alpha'],#32,
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type="CAUSAL_LM"
)


config['per_device_train_batch_size']
# Initialize SFTTrainer
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=config['output_dir'],
    per_device_train_batch_size=config['per_device_train_batch_size'],
    gradient_accumulation_steps=config['gradient_accumulation_steps'],
    learning_rate=float(config['learning_rate']),
    max_steps=config['max_steps'],
    optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
    fp16=True,
    load_best_model_at_end = True,
    save_strategy="epoch",  # Save at the end of each epoch
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=1  # Keep only the last 2 checkpoints
)

callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=2)]

supervised_finetuning_trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    args=training_args,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    peft_config=qlora_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=config['max_seq_length'],
    # data_collator=DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer, pad_to_multiple_of=8, return_tensors="pt", padding=True),
    callbacks=callbacks
)

# Train the model
supervised_finetuning_trainer.train()
```

Seeking insights or suggestions on why larger batch sizes, which are within GPU memory limits, result in significantly longer training times. Any advice or similar experiences would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
per_device_train_batch_size

Answer (score 0):

It was `max_steps` changing to epochs have the expected behavior.